# Echo number without scientific notation, while removing trailing zeros and decimal points

Tags: php, printf, scientific-notation

This:

```
function output($x) {
    return (float)($x==0 ? '0' : rtrim(($x<0 ? rtrim(sprintf('%.8F', $x), "0") : $x), "."));
}

    echo output(0.00008659);
```

Outputs:

```
8.659E-5
```

I want it to output this:

```
0.00008659
```

The reason why I'm using all those `rtrim's` and `if's` is because I want to remove trailing zeros when the number has less than 8 decimal places.
For example, `1.0000` should output `1`, `1.02000` should output `1.02`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function output($x) {
 $f = sprintf('%0.08f', $x);
 $f = rtrim($f,'0');
 $f = rtrim($f,'.');
 return $f;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for eg, 0.00000000000008605900, but the OP didn't say if he *always* wanted decimal notation or just *in this specific case*.

Comment: It works! I don't know why I complicate so much sometimes, thanks!

Comment: @bishop I'll only need to work with 8 decimal places, so this works just fine.

Comment: @user2536244 Since I gave you the answer, I still have to make sure you learned something :-) The lesson is: KISS (keep it simple stupid!). You might save a little overhead using your one-liner, but, even if it worked, the cost to readability and maintainability isn't worth it.